# Python socket post json request with header

Tags: python, json, sockets, post

i need very important time in milliseconds and need very fast send post json request 
socket is very fast 
i  send data by socket but after run script in wait and no response

code

```
import socket
import time
import ssl
start_time1 = time.time()
target_host = "site.com" 
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
target_port = 443  # create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(( target_host,443 ))
s = context.wrap_socket(s,server_hostname=target_host)

request = "POST /api/send HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:site.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0\r\nCookie: .ASPXAUTH=D6CA254ED2327019933D1746092C47DD2884398658FF3DCAD213B8B9F0F73F7A67BC0C483F316F76195B49BC2C487783F9C73009B3469F1F7BCE6286C6C16A45916A013285E23808DED1C2F8E65262C377923823B538CFCC;\r\n{'IsSymbolCautionAgreement': 'false', 'CautionAgreementSelected': 'false', 'IsSymbolSepahAgreement': 'false', 'SepahAgreementSelected': 'false', 'orderCount': 112, 'orderPrice': 45150, 'FinancialProviderId': '1', 'minimumQuantity': '', 'maxShow': '0', 'orderId': '0', 'isin': 'IRO7NIRP0001', 'orderSide': '65', 'orderValidity': '74', 'orderValiditydate': 'null', 'shortSellIsEnabled': 'false', 'shortSellIncentivePercent': '0'}"
s.send(request.encode())
response = s.recv( 9999 )
s.close()
print request
print response + '\n'
print("--- %s seconds-total ---" % (time.time() - start_time1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code caused by the lack of knowledge of how HTTP works:

- there is no `Content-length` which describes the length of the HTTP body
- there is no proper separator between HTTP header and body
- and your code implicitly uses HTTP keep-alive but still wrongly expects the server to close the connection immediately after the response is done

> i need very important time in milliseconds and need very fast send post json request socket is very fast

This is a commonly used but typically wrong reason to use plain sockets instead of using a HTTP library. The overhead is not in the local code but is in connection establishment and data transfer, i.e. in network I/O and network latency. Established libraries do a better job in keeping this relevant overhead small than simply using a socket: proper libraries can use multiple HTTP requests over the same TCP connection, can use compressed content, can handle TLS session resume etc - all of this are parts which are more relevant for performance than the complexity of the locally executed code.

If you still insists on running your own HTTP stack then please study and follow the actual standards instead of implementing your own idea of what HTTP might look like.

Comment: @cmaxxx: All what I see is your original code which contains the problems I've described. Apart from that I've described more problems than just setting a header.

Comment: @cmaxxx: If you want to share longer lived updates you can add them to your question. If you want to share the current version of the code just do [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and share it.